# Get 2 Selected Layer out of the MapTableLayer

Tags: layers, java, geotools

I have a Method that calculates the Area of 2 Layers of different topologic Relations, which needs 2 collections.

In the Button where I use this method, I want to get just 2 of the selected Layers in the MapLayerTable.

Now I don't really have a clue how I can get this done.
I already have a code sample, where I just select one Layer (The first one):

```
for(int i = 0; i < map.layers().size(); i++){
    if(map.layers().get(i).isSelected){
        FeatureLayer layer1 = (FeatureLayer) map.layers().get(i);
        SimpleFeatureCollection coll1 = layer1.getSimpleFeatureSource.features();
     break;
     }
}
```

is it possible to upgrade this code, so it gets me only 2 Layers as SimpleFeatureCollection? (The first two selected)

Or is there an easier Method to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your two layers contain the same sort of features then this is a simple as:

```
    ArrayList<FeatureLayer> selected = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Layer l : map.layers()) {
        if (l.isSelected()) {
            selected.add((FeatureLayer) l);
        }
    }

    try {
        SimpleFeatureCollection coll1 = selected.get(0).getSimpleFeatureSource().getFeatures();
        SpatialIndexFeatureCollection coll = new SpatialIndexFeatureCollection(coll1);
        if (selected.size() > 1) {
            for (FeatureLayer fl : selected) {
                SimpleFeatureCollection coll2 = fl.getSimpleFeatureSource().getFeatures();
                coll.addAll(coll2);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
```

If you have a mismatch in feature types but some common attributes then you will need to investigate [the `DataUtilities` class](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/main/data.html) which provides tools for casting and converting `FeatureCollections`.

Comment: ♦  first thanks for the fast answer I think I understand what you show, but how can I get the selected Layers? (In your sample _**layer1**_ and  _**layer2**_). Without having the same Layer in coll1 and coll2?
btw, it is right, that _**layer1**_ and _**layer2**_ (should) be of the same sort of Feature.

Comment: ok I've added some code to show you how lists work in java